# 3d plot - horizontal settings of zlabel - rotating labels

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, label

How to set zlabel horizontal. I don't know why the rotation of labels doesn't work.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D                 
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import proj3d                 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[10,6])

ax = fig.gca(projection = '3d')
ax.azim = 58    
ax.elev = 17    

ax.plot(rx, ry, rz)
ax.set_xlabel(r'$x$ (m)', rotation=0)
ax.set_ylabel(r'$y$ (m)', rotation=0)
ax.set_zlabel(r'$z$ (m)', rotation=180)
```

Comment: can you tell us the data type of ax and what lib it is from?

Comment: I am sorry, I editted the question

Comment: is this the complete code becuase it is telling me rx ry and rz are not defined

Comment: No, the code for computing these arrays is long. Can I go to discussion with you? I will send you the whole code

Comment: sure, just send me the code

Comment: In a 3D plot the labels rotate together with the axes, so whatever you set for rotation is overwritten at draw time.